# Open source reporting tools to be embedded with .net core

Tags: .net, .net-core, reporting

I am looking for some ideas about the **free** reporting tools that could be used to integrate with SQL Server database. I have found few of them like:
https://sealreport.org/
The most important features I am looking for are:

1. authentication customization - to integrate with JWT tokens from central system
2. scheduled reporting - possibility to schedule report generation and email send including report as attachment
3. possibility to export report data to excel file
4. if possible - row level security features - to authorize somehow whether current user is authorize to see specific rows
5. the reporting will be embedded in an iframe in the main portal for the customers

Could recommend something from your perspective?

Comment: I am having a similar requirement, let us kow if you found a suitable open source reporting tool.

Comment: @iamadnan SO isn't a recommendation site. It's surprising this question hasn't been closed already. There are no free tools because reporting is *hard*. You can use grids ilke ag-Grid, and pivots like pivottable.js but preparing the data, customizing the reports, caching, scheduling is *not* trivial. And beyond some complexity point, why use a reporting tool instead of eg Graphana?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand what you are saying, there is no easy/free way of doing something complex as reporting. I would also prefer doing it without a tool if the requirements are simple but sometimes you need heavy customizations of the front-end which involves multiple custom style sheets which is maintenance nightmare and you are stuck.